# New to YAML: not parsing in Swift

Tags: swift, parsing, yaml, codable

Here's some yaml that I've generated :

```
byTeam:
    - t0: { description: "Find a video of an object being selected and deselected", bestAnswer: [ 0 ]}
    - t1: { description: "Reveal and hide numeric controls", bestAnswer: [ 1 ]}
    - t2: { description: "Reveal and hide the tools", bestAnswer: [ 2 ]}
```

the error I get when parsing this is:

```
no decode typeMismatch(Yams.Node.Mapping, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "assignments", intValue: nil), _YAMLCodingKey(stringValue: "Index 1", intValue: 1), CodingKeys(stringValue: "challenges", intValue: nil), _YAMLCodingKey(stringValue: "Index 0", intValue: 0), CodingKeys(stringValue: "byTeam", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Mapping but found Node instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

This is new data, nested further into an already working yaml file. It's intended to end up parsed into this structure:

```
    struct CodableChallenge : Codable {
        var title :                     String
        var type :                      String
        var description :               String
        var uuid :                      UUID
        var videos :                    Array<String>
        var bestAnswer :                Array<Int>
        var userAnswer :                Array<Int>?
        var byTeam :                    Dictionary<String, TeamChallenge>?
    }
    
    struct TeamChallenge : Codable {
        var description :               String
        var bestAnswer :                Array<Int>
    }
```

The code generating the error is

```
 do {
            let decoded = try decoder.decode(MenuScreenVC.CodableCurriculum.self, from: src)
            manifestObsolete = curriculum == nil || decoded.referenceDate! > curriculum!.referenceDate!
            self.newManifest = decoded
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("gotManifest"), object: nil)
            return
        } catch {
            print("no decode \(error)")
        }
```

I am not completely unfamiliar with yaml, I used it a lot years ago with RoR. But I think what's escaping me is the deeper nesting. The error seems to indicate that it's getting data that doesn't look like straightforward mapping, but why?

Comment: I have to ask, why yaml instead of the more common json format? And what decoder are you using?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson Because YAML is awesome? :)

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: primarily because these files will eventually be maintained by non-tech/non-coders (at least at times), and my experience is that asking people to manage closures leads to complete chaos.

Comment: hey @Alexander, you wouldn't want to demonstrate how awesome yaml is by helping me understand the correct syntax for this situation, would you?

Comment: @DanDonaldson Hehehe clever hook, but I was already doing it :) Just posted my answer.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, I'm using the YAMS package in Swift

Comment: I'm not familiar with YAML, but usually, when I have issue with Decodable, I make my struct Codable (ie, I add the Encodable), which is already your case, I create my self an instance of the struct: `let challenge = CodableChallenge.init(title: "my title"...)`, and then call the encoder (in your case `YAMLDecoder`) and see what's the output. And check the what's the difference in the format. It might output what you're missing (could be a level, etc.)

Comment: Now that I got the chance to test, it works with `var byTeam : [Dictionary<String, TeamChallenge>]`, ie according to your YAML it's an array of dictionary, not a dictionary.

Comment: Keep also in mind that the YAML has a lot of "variants", so check the output options (`encoder.options = ...` value). But I'm not sure (since I never used that lib previously) if you can have different options for different "level/deepness"

Answer (score 0):

You're mixing arrays and dictionaries in a way that doesn't really make sense, and which doesn't match what your code expects.

Each tick mark starts a new object. Each colon-suffixed label demarks a key in an object. So what you've written is in effect:

```yaml
byTeam: [
    { t0: { ... } },
    { t1: { ... } },
    { t2: { ... } },
]
```

You just need to get rid of these `tN` values:

```yaml
byTeam:
    - { description: "Find a video of an object being selected and deselected", bestAnswer: [ 0 ]}
    - { description: "Reveal and hide numeric controls", bestAnswer: [ 1 ]}
    - { description: "Reveal and hide the tools", bestAnswer: [ 2 ]}
```

Although using the JSON-style object syntax (`{}`) might not be warranted in this case. I think it's more clear to use the normal YAML syntax:

```yaml
byTeam:
  - description: "Find a video of an object being selected and deselected"
    bestAnswer: [0]

  - description: "Reveal and hide numeric controls"
    bestAnswer: [1]

  - description: "Reveal and hide the tools"
    bestAnswer: [2]
```

(Adding spacing lines between the array items isn't necessary by the YAML grammar, but can help readability in some cases. Play with it to see what's best, especially if it might help your non-technical audience to better understand these.)

Comment: but without an explicit key, I'm forced to trust the implicit relationiship of the position in what is basically just an Array. The point of the keys is to provide explicit relationships, such as when the individual entry is detached from the context of the Array.

Comment: also, the key can encode for not just the ordinal value, but also encode for other things using t0, x0, etc.

Comment: @DanDonaldson Arrays are ordered, so you can rely on that on its own. If you want your data models in Swift to know their positions, that's something you can build into the models, without needing it to be redundantly encoded in the YAML. You can use either a dictionary, or an array, but the mix of both in this way is rather odd. It could still work, it's just not what your code is written to expect.

Comment: What's `t0` vs `x0`? I don't understand the scheme you're trying to establish here

Comment: "the normal YAML syntax:" : yes, I did do that as well, what's provided is not the first attempt.... I think the question I have is, "why is it difficult to include keys here?"

Comment: t0 might be an answer used in one context that hasn't been answered by the user previously. x0 (hypothetically, but likely) might be an answer the user has provide previously, where an associated quiz should not be shown, but instead only the correct answer. I think it's pretty easy to imagine any number of ways that such data might be encoded.

Comment: "Arrays are ordered, so you can rely on that on its own." Of course. But as I'm pointing out, ordering is not the only value here. These structs are used throughout an existing app, and it's really not my intention to push changes at that level into everyone's code, just because it's (or is it?) difficult to nest dictionaries. Think also about multiple entries that have the same ordinal position. That's much easier to represent using a key than assumption about arrays, which is always going to be fragile.

Comment: What you're describing sounds like it's perhaps an `id` field of these models? In that case, you might want to put it inside the model, rather than in this 1-key-outter warpping dictionary. Although it's not quite an identifier, because whether or not the user has already provided an answer isn't par of the _identity_ of the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256413/discussion-between-dan-donaldson-and-alexander).